# How to create a Merge Request in order for code review after the files are already merged?

Tags: git, gitlab

I wrote several new files and ran git add, git commit and git push to gitlab. After that I realized that I was working on the main branch, so these files were directly merged without my team reviewing them.

What I should have done was to make the changes at my own branch, after git push to gitlab, I create a Merge Request at gitlab. Then my team could review the MR.

So what can I do now in order to create MR? Do I have to delete those file from gitlab repo first (is it possible to delete files?) ?

Answer (score 0):

If the files have already been merged, it's too late to create a Merge Request for code review, as the purpose of a Merge Request is to propose changes to be merged into the codebase. Once changes have been merged, they are already part of the codebase and it's no longer possible to create a Merge Request for them.

However, you can still review the changes that were made. This might involve creating an issue or a code review comment on the relevant changeset.

Comment: Creating an issue for code review? How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, neither of which are exactly what you're asking for. They'll allow for a code review by showing a diff, but not a pull/merge request.

1. Check out the commit on the main branch prior to the merge. Create a branch from that. Then create a pull request from your dev branch to that new branch. It simulates the diff to the main branch prior to the merge. The actual merge is meaningless, though, since the destination branch is junk.
2. Just do a diff to the commit prior to the merge. This allows you to see the changes.